# UPDATE records using REST api

Tags: php, rest, salesforce, integration

I am working on PHP and Salesforce integration and I want to update records using PHP.

[image: desired layout]

I want to update records in Salesforce when clicking on the Button "Follow up".
And also try the below code.

```
function update_account($id, $followup, $instance_url, $access_token) {
$url = "$instance_url/services/data/v20.0/sobjects/Contact/$id";


$content = json_encode(array("shivendra__FollowUp__c" => $followup));
echo $content;
$curl = curl_init($url);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_HEADER, false);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER,
        array("Authorization: OAuth $access_token",
            "Content-type: application/json"));
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, "PATCH");
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $content);

curl_exec($curl);

$status = curl_getinfo($curl, CURLINFO_HTTP_CODE);

if ( $status != 204 ) {
    die("Error: call to URL $url failed with status $status, curl_error " . curl_error($curl) . ", curl_errno " . curl_errno($curl));
}
echo "<b>update_contact function</b>";
echo "HTTP status $status updating Contact<br/><br/>";

curl_close($curl);
}
```

But getting an error:

> {"shivendra__FollowUp__c":null}
>
> [{"errorCode":"METHOD_NOT_ALLOWED","message":"HTTP Method 'PATCH' not allowed. Allowed are HEAD,GET,POST"}]
>
> Error: call to URL https://shivendra-dev-ed.my.salesforce.com/services/data/v20.0/sobjects/Contact/ failed with status 405, curl_error , curl_errno 0

Answer (score 0):

Try the post method with cURL, similar to this:

`curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);`